# Free Up Port 53 on Ubuntu so costom DNS server can use it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, bind

I am implementing custom DNS server, but when I try using it, it clashes with port 53 being in use.
Changing resolved.config file doesn't help.
My resolved.conf file looks like this:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=127.0.0.1
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
```

My /etc/resolv.conf file looks like this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.1.1
search lan1
```

Port 53 is sill used to resolve dns...

```
$ sudo lsof -i :53
COMMAND   PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE     
systemd-r 636 systemd-resolve   12u  IPv4  22828   
0t0  UDP             127.0.0.53:domain 
systemd-r 636 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  22829      0t0  TCP   
127.0.0.53:domain (LISTEN)
```

When I run custom Dns Server I get an error,

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 466, in   
server_bind
self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice

Answer (score 5):

[How to stop systemd-resolved from using port 53 on Ubuntu](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/07/ubuntu-how-to-free-up-port-53-used-by.html)

You can find a nifty tutorial in the link above.  Below I'll note what's in the tutorial for visibility.

As root, edit the **/etc/systemd/resolved.conf** with your text editor of choice.

Now, you'll want to uncomment (*remove the #*) the **DNS=** and **DNSStubListener=** lines.

You'll now want to change the **DNS=** value to your DNS server of choice and then change the value of the **DNSStubListener=** from **yes** to **no**

Now, save your changes and exit the editor.

Next, you'll want to create a *symbolic link* for **/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf** with **/etc/resolv.conf** as the destination.

```
sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

You'll note the **-s**, which makes the link *symbolic* instead of a *hard link* and the **-f** is to remove any existing destination files.

Now, you should be able to reboot your system and be able to use **port 53**

You can check this by running the following command:

```
sudo lsof -i :53
```

If you see no output, then **port 53** should be open.

To undo this you'll edit the **/etc/systemd/resolved.conf** and put the settings back to the way it originally was.

Add the **#** back in front of the **DNS=** line and change the **DNSStubListener=** back to **no**.

Then you can remove that symbolic link by typing the following:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then reboot.

I really hope that helps!  Check out the link for a better visual ha ha.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  You can also run sudo service systemd-resolved restart and not need to "reboot" .  This worked in 22.04LTS

Answer (score 1):

```bash
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You may want to add a note _why_ you think this approach will solve the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

As was given in another answer, you can mostly follow the tutorial here: `https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/07/ubuntu-how-to-free-up-port-53-used-by.html`.  I won't rehash those specifics, but if that one didn't work you may have to make another modification.

You might have to turn off the DNSStubListener in another part of systemd.

Try editing the file `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/noresolved.conf` - if it has `DNSStubListener=yes`, change that to `DNSStubListener=no`.

It is possible there are other conf files which ave this set (under the `[Resolve]` specifier, so you may have to look around further.

Hope that helps.